# Load NSView with xib in NSViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, custom-view, nsviewcontroller

How to load NSView with xib in my NSViewController ? I want to reuse the custom nsview with xib in more than three nsviewcontroller(location).
How can i load the nsview xib in nsviewcontroller

Help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
+ (NSView *)loadWithNibNamed:(NSString *)nibNamed owner:(id)owner class:(Class)loadClass {

    NSNib * nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:nibNamed bundle:nil];

    NSArray * objects;
    if (![nib instantiateWithOwner:owner topLevelObjects:&objects]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't load nib named %@", nibNamed);
        return nil;
    }

    for (id object in objects) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:loadClass]) {
            return object;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

from this [repo](https://github.com/peterpaulis/NSView-NibLoading-/tree/master)